# Have famous grandmasters ever been checkmated?

Tags: checkmate, grandmaster

Whenever I watch chess games played by grandmasters, they usually resign far before reaching checkmate (often even before a forced checkmate occurs). However, I wonder if there are recent examples of famous grandmasters getting checkmated?

Would be interesting to see how the game looks in order for them to get checkmated. Is there any examples of this?

Comment: I think the issue here is time controls? Idk, in blitz/bullet, I think this is very common.

Comment: *Correction: relatively more common

Comment: oh wait wait more importantly, i forgot about time out. i was thinking checkmate vs resign. in the case of lower time controls, i was thinking of actually (checkmate OR time out) vs resign. ok surely as time controls decrease, we have that (checkmate OR time out) is very common right? that is so weird the 2 mistakes i made lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most recent super Grandmaster level checkmate I can think of is the game [Wesley So vs Hikaru Nakamura](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1800188), Sinquefield, Cup August 2015.

```
[White "Wesley So"]
[Black "Hikaru Nakamura"]
[Result "0-1"]
[FEN ""] 

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. O-O Nc6 8. d5
Ne7 9. Ne1 Nd7 10. f3 f5 11. Be3 f4 12. Bf2 g5 13. Nd3 Ng6 14. c5 Nf6 15. Rc1
Rf7 16. Kh1 h5 17. cxd6 cxd6 18. Nb5 a6 19. Na3 b5 20. Rc6 g4 21. Qc2 Qf8 22.
Rc1 Bd7 23. Rc7 Bh6 24. Be1 h4 25. fxg4 f3 26. gxf3 Nxe4 27. Rd1 Rxf3 28. 
Rxd7 Rf1+ 29. Kg2 Be3 30. Bg3 hxg3 31. Rxf1 Nh4+ 32. Kh3 Qh6 33. g5 Nxg5+ 34. 
Kg4 Nhf3 35. Nf2 Qh4+ 36. Kf5 Rf8+ 37. Kg6 Rf6+ 38. Kxf6 Ne4+ 39. Kg6 Qg5#
```

Comment: What's the time control please? I think the issue here for this question is time controls? Idk, in blitz/bullet, I think this is very common.

Comment: *Correction: relatively more common

Comment: oh wait wait more importantly, i forgot about time out. i was thinking checkmate vs resign. in the case of lower time controls, i was thinking of actually (checkmate OR time out) vs resign. ok surely as time controls decrease, we have that (checkmate OR time out) is very common right? that is so weird the 2 mistakes i made lol

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although over 10 years old, there is this, which I came across in Soltis' *Studying Chess Made Easy*.

```
[Event "Match"]    
[Date "2006"]  
[White "Deep Thought"]
[Black "Kramnik"]
[Result "1-0"]
[EventDate "2006.??.??"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[FEN "5N1k/q5p1/7p/8/pp2Q3/8/1P4PP/2b4K b - - 0 1"]

1...Qe3 2.Qh7# 1-0
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2019 sinquefield cup round 8 [game](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1971763) between Sergey Karjakin and Maxime Vachier-Lagrave , MVL allowed Karjakin to checkmate him.

MVL was appreciated for his sportsmanship.

Comment: What's the time control please? I think the issue here for this question is time controls? Idk, in blitz/bullet, I think this is very common.

Comment: @BCLC irrespective of time controls. GMs getting checkmated is not "very common", I assure you that.

Comment: srk_cb, oh that's weird i meant relatively more common. thanks for replying. i mean relatively, it's more common as time controls decrease? surely the percentage change can't just be statistically insignificant

Comment: srk_cb oh wait wait more importantly, i forgot about time out. i was thinking checkmate vs resign. in the case of lower time controls, i was thinking of actually (checkmate OR time out) vs resign. ok surely as time controls decrease, we have that (checkmate OR time out) is very common right? that is so weird the 2 mistakes i made lol

Answer (score 3):

An example from earlier this week, if admittedly blitz

```
[Event "6th Zurich Opening Blitz"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2017.04.12"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Pelletier, Yannick"]
[Black "Gelfand, Boris"]
[ECO "D15"]
[WhiteElo "2541"]
[BlackElo "2724"]
[Result "0-1"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. Nc3 e6 5. e3 Nbd7 6. Qc2 Bd6 7. b3 O-O 8. Be2 b6 9. O-O Bb7 10. Bb2 Qe7 11. Rad1 Rad8 12. Rfe1 Rfe8 13. Bf1 e5 14. cxd5 e4 15. Ne5 Nxe5 16. dxe5 Bxe5 17. dxc6 Bxh2+ 18. Kxh2 Ng4+ 19. Kg3 Qe5+ 20. f4 Qh5 21. Rxd8 Qh2+ 22. Kxg4 h5+ 23. Kg5 Qg3+ 24. Kxh5 g6+ 25. Kh6 Qh4#
```

Comment: Actually, I think the issue here for this question is time controls? Idk, in blitz/bullet, I think this is very common. After a certain point of increasing time controls, I think checkmate should never happen (unless 2 GMs really decide to play a game to checkmate specifically to really disprove people like me making these claims).

Comment: *Correction: relatively more common

Comment: oh wait wait more importantly, i forgot about time out. i was thinking checkmate vs resign. in the case of lower time controls, i was thinking of actually (checkmate OR time out) vs resign. ok surely as time controls decrease, we have that (checkmate OR time out) is very common right? that is so weird the 2 mistakes i made lol